# Dealing with colored text on Routers/Switches using expect script

Tags: unix, scripting, router, expect

I am trying to login to a router using an expect script. Now, normally, my script works fine when the text on the remote device is not colored.

But when the text on the device is colored, the script fails to authenticate and login to the device.

I googled and I understand that it has something to do with the ANSI color code sequences.

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/expect
    set hostName [lindex $argv 0]

    spawn telnet $hostName

    expect "Username:"
    send "userid\n"

    expect "Password:"
    send "pswdstring\n"

    expect "*#"
    send "quit"
```

Here are my observations:

1. I can login successfully to the device manually. The colored text is still printing on the console, but there is no issue in authentication.
2. When I redirect the output of the script to a file, I can see the ANSI color codes

Snippet of the output:

```
   [33mNo/expired credentials.
    [m[33mUsername: [muserid
    [33mPassword: [mpswdstring
```

I know that the color escape sequence is appending to the actual userid and passwords entered and causing authentication failure. I tried sending a backspace character but that dint work too.

Please help in dealing with these color codes. I an executing the script from Solaris machine.

Comment: The escape codes you're seeing are only in the OUTPUT though, right? If you aren't sending them, they aren't part of the username and password that's being evaluated. Can you turn on debug logging and see if there's a failed login attempt from a user named `[muserid`?

Comment: Also, [*this*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4527/13377) lists a number of options for stripping colour codes from your output.

Comment: Yes, the escape codes aren't part of the username and passwords being evaluated. I am sending 'userid' and 'pswdsring' as credentials. And yes, the '[m' is getting appended to the user id and password strings and that results in a failed login attempt.

Comment: Sorry, that still isn't making sense to me. The colour codes are being sent FROM the switch, as part of how it displays things to you. How would the switch use some of what it sends do you as something to authenticate on? Have you checked debug logs? What do they say is the auth username in these failed attempts?

Comment: You are probably sending the password before the remote is ready for it, since you match for the `:` and there are still characters following. A simple thing to try is adding a small `sleep 1` after each  expect and before the send.

Comment: @meuh Thanks! That was the issue. I added `sleep 1` after both username and password prompts. And that worked! I was able to login. Thanks again!

Comment: @ghoti I checked the debug logs and it correctly showed 'userid' as the username. And in between, there was a expect: timed out statement. It was confusing because I couldn't figure out which expect statement was not matching. But, its working now, after adding the sleep statement.

Comment: Well, I'm glad that you realize that escape sequences were in fact NOT being sent back to the server as part of the login process. Remember always to challenge your assumptions!